# SQL Server allowing incorrect domain name to be given for NTLM auth

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious, node-mssql, ntlm-authentication

**Summary**

Using the nodejs [tedious driver](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious), I am able to specify *any* domain name to connect to my instance of SQL Server via NTLM authentication, and am then capable of querying the database with this connection.

**Background**

The tedious driver is used as the db connector for essentially all of the popular node SQL Server modules ([node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql), [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)), and unsurprisingly I am encountering this issue when testing with all three modules.

Historically I believe this hasn't been an issue so I am starting to wonder if maybe this has to do with the configuration of the Windows box that I am using (Win Server 2016). Unfortunately my knowledge of Windows administration is lacking.

There is currently an [issue filed against the official GitHub for the tedious driver](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/875) that covers exactly what I'm experiencing, but I don't see how the driver could be the source of this.

**Things I've Tried**

- VMs that are connected to a Windows domain
- VMs that are not connected to a Windows domain
- Connecting with a user that isn't the default Administrator
- Checking the Event Viewer logs after a successful login attempt

  - this shows the SecurityID, Account Name, and Account Domain as all the correct values (rather than the *incorrect* ones that I specify in the connection configuration)

**Reproduction**

npm install tedious

```
let config = {
  server: '<server ip>',
  port: 1433,
  authentication: {
    type: 'ntlm',
    options: {
        domain: 'WRONGDOMAIN',
        userName: 'Administrator', // update me
        password: 'password' // update me
    }
  },
  options: {
    database: '<database name>'
  }
}
```

I can then connect to the database *regardless* of what the domain value is, as long as the user has the required permissions.